# Spinner OnItemSelectedListener

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I can't find an example of how to do this in mono.

Any help?

Edit: Added code

```
foreach (equip item in list)
   {
        tr = new TableRow(this);

        sp = new Spinner(this);
        sp.LayoutParameters = lp2;
        sp.Adapter = adapter;                                  
        sp.ItemSelected += new EventHandler<ItemEventArgs>(spinner_ItemSelected());
        sp.SetSelection(Convert.ToInt32(item.status));
        tr.AddView(sp);
   }

private void spinner_ItemSelected(object sender, ItemEventArgs e)
    {
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner)sender;

        string toast = string.Format ("You selected {0}", spinner.GetItemAtPosition (e.Position));
        Toast.MakeText (this, toast, ToastLength.Long).Show ();
    }
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In Mono for Android a lot of listener interfaces have been translated to C# events, including this one. In this case you can hook into the [ItemSelected](http://docs.mono-android.net/?link=E%3aAndroid.Widget.AdapterView.ItemSelected) event instead of having to create a listener. Xamarin has a full example of using a spinner available [here](http://docs.xamarin.com/android/tutorials/User_Interface/spinner).

**Edit:**

Based on your request to differentiate when the spinner value has actually changed, you can do something like:

```
int initialSpinnerPosition = spinner.SelectedItemPosition;
spinner.ItemSelected += (sender, args) =>
                        {
                            if (args.Position != initialSpinnerPosition)
                            {
                                // do stuff
                            }
                        };
```

Comment: Thanks.  That seems to work except I need it not to fire the event OnCreate.  See I am dynamically generating the spinners based on a SQL query and will be setting the value of the spinner to the previously selected value stored in the DB during OnCreate.  I need the event to only fire after that if the user selects something different.

Comment: When the event fires you could check the new value against the original one to see if it has changed.

Comment: I guess my question is how to do that.  Once the value is changed, how do I compare it to the value that no longer exists? I've added my code to give you a better idea of what I'm doing

Comment: As always Greg, very helpful.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

you can use the tag like

```
bool userClick = false;

spinner.ItemSelected += (sender, e) => {
            if(userClick) {
                --- do stuff
            }
            userClick = true;
        };
```

When you create/update the spinners adapter based on a SQL Data

```
userClick = false;
```